# Serialize LocalDateTime with play json issue

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a Person case class:

```
case class Person(name: String, createdAt: LocalDateTime)
```

to be able to serialize person object to json so I can return it to the user 
I have a serualizer:

```
object PersonSerializer {
  implicit val PersonFormat: OFormat[Person] = Json.format[Person]
}
```

and I import this serializer in the controller so when I can return the result to the use as json like this:

```
def getPeople: Action[AnyContent] = Action.async {
    peopleDao.getAllPeople.map(people => Ok(Json.toJson(res)))
}
```

BUT, I get this error:

> Error:(39, 55) No instance of play.api.libs.json.Format is available
>   for org.joda.time.LocalDateTime in the implicit scope (Hint: if
>   declared in the same file, make sure it's declared before)   implicit
>   val AFormat: OFormat[Account] = Json.format[Account]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is pretty much in the stacktrace. Basically, in order to format a `Person`, Play's serializer needs to know how to serialize a `LocalDateTime`. You should try something like:

```
object PersonSerializer {
    implicit val LocalDateFormat: OFormat[LocalDateFormat] = 
        new OFormat[LocalDateFormat](){ /*...*/ }
    implicit val PersonFormat: OFormat[Person] = Json.format[Person]
}
```

I suggest you to look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31462673/how-to-use-joda-datetime-with-play-json), this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37342498/how-to-create-oformat-from-format-in-scala-and-play-framework?rq=1), and the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJsonCombinators).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using of jsoniter-scala: https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala

You will get build in support of `java.time.*` classes with more than 10x times greater throughput for parsing & serialisation.

Just see results of ArrayOfLocalDateFormatBenchmark for Jsoniter-scala vs. Circe, Jackson and Play-JSON: http://jmh.morethan.io/?source=https://plokhotnyuk.github.io/jsoniter-scala/oraclejdk8.json